# LibreOffice not rendering gradient fill properly

Tags: rendering, libreoffice, linear-gradients

I have Dell XPS 15, I installed LibreOffice only to come across gradient rendering issue. I created a rectangle, filled it with gradient and sent it behind text. I closed and opened document and I have issue of gradient filling partially not rendering:
[image]

[image]

This happens only for gradients. Is there any setting I could tweak to prevent it?

P.S. I just tried rotating gradient and it breaks depending on angle:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for rendering issue of gradients on LibreOffice.

Go to Tools -> Options -> View and untick 'Use Skia for all rendering'
[image]
After this there were no more issues with displaying gradients:
[image]